# 14.04 Udisks2 Not Auto-Mounting External Drives

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I've upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 via command-line when my system froze, had to do REISUB and dpkg --configure -a to recover from crash after rebooting.

Now everything seems to work *except* automatically mounting external thumb drives and external hard disk drives. After plugging in said drives, it'll show up on the left pane but remains unmounted. Had to click on it before it mounts.

I believe my problem has something to do with Udisks2 but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems like I solved my own problem.

I deleted `.compiz`, `.config` and `.local` directories save for some folders containing configuration for my most-used applications (such as Gedit and Geany).

I had to do it from a terminal session without logging into graphical Unity since it'll just rebuild/re-save the `.compiz` directory and its current configuration.

I logged in soon after, and was surprised to find out that my external drives are auto-mounting.

So it doesn't seem to be a problem with Udisk2, rather a mis-configured user setting. Though I wonder which setting is at fault here.